# Adding elements to an array from a sql query

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to add the returned items from the query to the array. I have already searched similar topics, but I have not been able to properly modify the code to get the table I need.
I am trying to add to the array those elements that contain a category (i.e. those that are not empty). I've used the count function before, but to no avail. When I display an array outside the loop, it shows me all the elements, including the empty ones. I suppose I have a poorly constructed conditional. How should I fix the code to make it work properly?
Thanks for any help

```
public static function findEmpikCategoryFromEmpikCategories($colectionLilante) {
            // print_r($colectionLilante);
            $empikCategory = [];
    
            $pdo = PDOConnector::getConnection();
            
            foreach($colectionLilante as $collection)
            {
                // print_r($collection);
                $query = "SELECT empik_category FROM `empik_categories` WHERE lilante_category='$collection' LIMIT 1";
                // echo "</br>";
            

                $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
                $stmt->execute();
                
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    // print_r($row); 
                    if($row['empik_category'])
                    {
                        $empikCategory[] = $row['empik_category'];
                    }
                                            
                }


            }
            // echo "</br>";
            print_r($empikCategory);

            return $empikCategory;
        }
```

Comment: hi, what kind of data type is in $collection?

Comment: @spinsch - it is string

Comment: Rule of thumb: Do proper return checks. Your `if($row['empik_category'])` is a little vague. I assume you intend to check for a `return_value !== FALSE` sort of thing, but what if you're dealing with an empty array? Depending on your database schema and contents this is what may be returned! So check what your call returns against both  type and value. Using a simple `if($blah)` and assuming that that will always work as you had in mind can be a little risky.

Comment: For what it's worth, `lilante_category='$collection'` is just a regular PHP variable, the syntax for a prepared statement would be something like `lilante_category=:collection` or `lilante_category=?`.

Comment: Problem solved, it turned out that the while condition was in the wrong place. It should be in the function from which I pass the array with string values to the function implemented above, while in the while loop where elements that have met the condition are only added to the returned array.